# Plotting raster by attributes in R?

Tags: raster, r

I am new to spatial analysis! I need to plot some data from FAO's world soil map found [here](http://www.fao.org/soils-portal/soil-survey/soil-maps-and-databases/harmonized-world-soil-database-v12/en/). The description of the data suggests it should have multiple attributes (e.g. elevation, slope etc). When I download the raster, however, it doesn't have any attributes.

What am I doing wrong?

```
x<-raster("hwsd.bil")
ratify(x)

> ratify(x)
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 21600, 43200, 933120000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : C:/Users/jam/Desktop/graph/hwsd.bil 
names      : hwsd 
values     : 0, 32049  (min, max)
attributes :
        ID
 from: 0
 to : 32050
```

Comment: http://webarchive.iiasa.ac.at/Research/LUC/External-World-soil-database/HTML/HWSD_Data.html?sb=4 has links to the raster and the mdb that work, unlike the FAO mdb link which gives me a permission denied error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

```
2.2   Database   Contents   
The HWSD is composed of a GIS raster image file linked to 
 an attribute database in Microsoft Access format.
```

The raster image file has code numbers which need to be looked up in the attribute database to get the information at that pixel. Its not stored in the raster.

The MDB file has a table called `HWSD_DATA`. The `ID` column of this corresponds to the value in the raster. So for example there's a pixel near Switzerland that has value 9656, and in the table it has:

```
     ID MU_GLOBAL MU_SOURCE1 MU_SOURCE2 ISSOIL SHARE SEQ SU_SYM74 SU_CODE74
1: 9656     10267     490089     490322      1     5   6                 NA
   SU_SYM85 SU_CODE85 SU_SYM90 SU_CODE90 T_TEXTURE DRAINAGE REF_DEPTH AWC_CLASS
1:       Od       156      HSf        89         3        1       100         1
   PHASE1 PHASE2 ROOTS IL SWR ADD_PROP T_GRAVEL T_SAND T_SILT T_CLAY
1:     NA     NA     1  1   4        0        1     20     40     40
   T_USDA_TEX_CLASS T_REF_BULK_DENSITY  T_OC T_PH_H2O T_CEC_CLAY T_CEC_SOIL
1:                3               1.26 33.63      4.3         45         77
   T_BS T_TEB T_CACO3 T_CASO4 T_ESP T_ECE S_GRAVEL S_SAND S_SILT S_CLAY
1:   62  31.4       0       0     2   0.1        2     47     26     27
   S_USDA_TEX_CLASS S_REF_BULK_DENSITY  S_OC S_PH_H2O S_CEC_CLAY S_CEC_SOIL
1:               10               1.38 32.89      4.6         71         78
   S_BS S_TEB S_CACO3 S_CASO4 S_ESP S_ECE T_BULK_DENSITY S_BULK_DENSITY
1:   40  27.4       0       0     1   0.1            0.1            0.1
```

Some of those values are again categories that need to be looked up in the other tables. All this is well-documented in the technical guide.

To read the MDB into R I've used the Linux `mdb-tools` package to export tables into CSV format, and then read them in using `data.table::fread`. Any linking is probably best done "manually" depending on your query. For example if you want all areas where some column in the data is some given value, query the CSV data frame and use the ID values in the result to find the pixels in the raster that have those values.

If you don't have the `mdbtools` then I guess MS Access can export CSV files from its tables.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will try to access the .mdb database. How can I link it to raster in R? Thanks!